# Upcall Javascript to JavaFX

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx

I want to learn more about JavaFX and so I tried to set up Webview. 
I copied the webview example from the Oracle website and added Upcall functionality. 
But it isn't working. Actually I have no idea how to debug a website in Webview. 
So here is the java code:

```
package boersensim;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;


public class Main extends Application {
private Scene scene;
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    // create the scene
    stage.setTitle("Web View");
    scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    //scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
}
class Browser extends Region {

final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

public Browser() {
    //apply the styles
    getStyleClass().add("browser");
    // load the web page
    webEngine.load("test.html");
    //add the web view to the scene
    getChildren().add(browser);

    JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
    jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
}
private Node createSpacer() {
    Region spacer = new Region();
    HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
    return spacer;
}

@Override protected void layoutChildren() {
    double w = getWidth();
    double h = getHeight();
    layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
}

@Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
    return 750;
}

@Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
    return 500;
}
}

class Bridge {
public void exit() {
    //Platform.exit();
    System.out.print("Hello!UPCALL");
}
}
```

The corrosponding HTML is:

```
Click<a href="#" onclick="java.exit();">here</a>to exit the application
```

When I click the link nothing happens.

Thanks to you in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

set Bridge() on page loaded event

```
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {                        
                        JSObject jso = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        jso.setMember("java", new Bridge());
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

I also followed this tutorial (probably the one you used): 
https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx

And found that it makes the JVM crash. So I reported an issue on the JavaFX jira, and I got the following reply:

> It is a requirement since 7u5 that the methods called from JS be accessible in Java sense, i.e. >public members of public classes. (This is mentioned in the last comment to the article). In this >particular test case Bridge should be declared a public class.
>
> The crash was fixed in JDK8. Now an exception is thrown.

And that works.

Comment: If I had only seen this response 3 hours ago! I had a static inner class *without* the `public` modifier, and the JVM crashes. Added `public` to the class and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Three things to be change in you code Daniel,

1) Make your class Bridge **public**
2) Enable JavaScript like this `webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
3) set Member Bridge() on page loaded event like bellow

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, State oldValue, State newValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {                        
                 JSObject jso = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                 jso.setMember("java", new Bridge());
             }

        }
    });
```

Welcome, Daniel