# Inject a JS<->JavaFX bringe to WebView on page load

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-8

I need to inject a bridge object before JavaScript execution starts (or, at least, before `document.onready` is triggered). The most frequent solution does not provide it:

```
engine.getLoadWorker().getStateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State> {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> val, State oldV, State newV) {
        if (newV == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            System.out.println("getLoadWorker.stateProperty changed to " + newV + ", injecting an API!");
            ((JSObject) engine.executeScript("window")).setMember("api", new SomeApi());
        }
    }
});
```

But a simple test case shows that JavaScipt gets called before state transition happens:

```
alert("Loaded! typeof(api) == '" + typeof(api) + "'");
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Ready! typeof(api) == '" + typeof(api) + "'");
});
```

This sample ouputs something like:

```
[JS alert] Loaded! typeof(api) == 'undefined'
[JS alert] Ready! typeof(api) == 'undefined'
getLoadWorker.stateProperty changed to SUCCEEDED, injecting an API!
```

Another suggested answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414332/1848172) seems to work, but looks like an ugly hack. Is there any clean solution?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400925/inject-bridge-code-in-javafx-webview-before-page-load/28414332#28414332) you mentioned only works if you have access to the source of the page, as you have to inject your magic state there.

Another ugly way is to basically load a local HTML page, which is essential an iFrame into which you then load the content. This way you might be able to inject your javascript into the locally loaded page and afterwards load the actual page through JavaScript. However it all depends on the JavaScript you want to execute.